# how to solve this Facebook SDK 4.0 login button exception

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am using Facebook SDK 4.0 in an android app for login, the code is as follows

```
 loginButton = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions("user_friends");

    // Other app specific specialization


    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    // Callback registration
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            // App code
            Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();

            Log.d("facebook",profile.getId());


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            // App code
            Log.d("facebook","failed");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            // App code
            Log.d("facebook","failed");
        }
    });

 @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


}
```

When Facebook app on device (Genymotion nexus 5 5.0.0 ROM) is in logged out state following exception is generated

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=64206, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity

I have tried many options including making Facebook app live ( production from developer) still it doesn't work and fails to get any profile information at this line

```
Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();

Log.d("facebook",profile.getId());
```

The Genymotion ROM I'm using doesn't have developer mode enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in app settings SSO was turned off, after turning ON now it doesn't crash on Weblogin

Comment: also came across this tutorial, neatly addresses how to use 4.X sdk http://code2care.org/2015/facebook-android-sdk-v4.1.0-integration-android-studio/

Answer (score 0):

Did you initialize facebook sdk?

If you didn't, add this code onCreate or somewere before you use facebook sdk.

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
```